# Is there a limit to amount of bluetooth devices connected to a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bluetooth, mouse, headphones

Problems arose today when I connected the 5th bluetooth device to my MacBook Pro.

- 1 new Apple keyboard
- 1 new Apple trackpad
- 1 old Apple keyboard
- 1 old Apple mouse (most recently connected)
- 1 Beats Wireless

After connecting the mouse, I suddenly started hearing skipping through the headset whenever I clicked keys on a keyboard or moved the mouse around. Reverting back to 4 bluetooth devices "fixed it". Interestingly, using the Trackpad did not have the same effect.

Any thoughts on how to fix this? Or is this simply a hardware limitation?

Due to pair programming I actually do need to have all devices connected (although I can use a cable for some if this is a `wontfix`).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the info from [Apple site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201171):

> **Connect multiple Bluetooth devices to one computer**
>
> The official Bluetooth specifications say seven is the maximum number of Bluetooth devices that can be connected to your Mac at once.
> However, three to four devices is a practical limit, depending on the types of devices used. Some devices require more Bluetooth data, so they're more demanding than other devices. Data-intensive devices might reduce the total number of devices that can be active at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I can connect 8 BLE devices (Bluetooth Low Energy), but when connecting an Apple keyboard and mouse, I can only connect 4 BLE devices.

Seems like regular Bluetooth (2.0) uses the bandwidth of 2 BLE devices.

This is on a MacbookPro 2015 model.

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed seem to be a bandwidth limitation with MacOS Bluetooth, I can only manage 3 atm on an M1 Macbook Pro:

1. Bluetooth keyboard (Air75)
2. Bluetooth receiver for wired speakers OR Sennheiser Momentum headphones
3. Wacom Intuous

Note the absence of a mouse (Logitech MX Master), as I had to sacrifice something in order for the Wacom to be usable! From my limited testing, music + wacom seems to eat the bandwidth.